# Finding object in list not working properly in django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to check if the date a user picked is not already booked. I wrote the codes below, and after inputting a date that has been booked in the db, I was informed that the date is free which is not supposed to be.

Models

property models

```
class Kip(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

property owner calender models

```
class OwnerCalendar(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    kip=models.ForeignKey(Kip)
    booked_dates=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
```

booking of property models

```
class Bookable(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    event_date=models.DateField()
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_no=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    kip=models.ForeignKey(Kip)
```

Views

```
def booking_of_space(request, kipid):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=BookableForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            newbooking=Bookable(
                user=request.user,
                pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                event_date=data['event_date'],
                phone_no=data['phone_no'],
                kip=Kip.objects.get(pk=kipid),
                session=Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key))
            newbooking.save()
            renter=newbooking.event_date
          owners=OwnerCalendar.objects.filter(kip__id=kipid).values_list('booked_dates')
            if renter in owners:
                return HttpResponse('Booked already')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Go ahead and book')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Kindly input the right data')
    else:
        return render_to_response('bookablespace.html',{'BookableForm':BookableForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You are comparing a date object (`newbooking.event_date`) against a list of strings (`booked_dates`) which will never be true. Why not just do a query to check if there is a `Bookable` entry already created for a property at a certain time?

Comment: kindly explain further. can you give me an idea on how to go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a date object `newbooking.event_date` against a list of strings `booked_dates` which will never be true. Why not just do a query to check if there is a `Bookable` entry already created for a property at a certain time? Something like:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        data=form.cleaned_data
        requested_date = data['event_date']
        requested_kip = Finapart.objects.get(pk=kipid)
        existing_bookings = Bookable.objects.filter(
            kip = requested_kip,
            event_date = requested_date
        )
        if existing_bookings: 
            return HttpResponse('Booked already')
        newbooking=Bookable(
            user=request.user,
            pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
            event_date=requested_date,
            phone_no=data['phone_no'],
            kip=requested_kip,
            session=Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key))
        newbooking.save()
        return HttpResponse('Booking saved')
    ...
```

Comment: this is how it works: Property owner update his calendar through OwnerCalendar models so when a property renter wants to book, it will check the property owner calendar `OwnerCalendar` if it's available so the renter can move forward. With your solution, I think it will render the `Ownercalendar` useless. What do you think?

Comment: In your code, there's no how I can check for already booked dates in property owner calendar. Kindly explain why you did that. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to save booking dates in the `OwnerCalendar` model as you already have that information in your `Bookable` model; an entry in the `Bookable` model at a certain date in a certain property

Comment: The `Ownercalendar booked_dates` is a field for property owner to input already booked dates. and the `Bookable event_date` is a field for property renters to input their preferred date they want to book the property. I don't think an information about `OwnerCalendar` models exist in `Bookable` apart from the property itself which is `Kip` . Hope you get my point?

Comment: Thanks man. I did a tweak and it worked. I will fix your answer and give you the credit.